# Connect to Salesforce.com from Excel Macro

Tags: excel, salesforce, vba

Is there a way I can connect to Salesforce.com through Excel Macro?

As we pull data from Oracle DB by creating a DB connect string, is it possible to do a similar setup for Salesforce too?

I am aware salesforce provides "Connect for Office" plugin but the problem with that plug in is it degrades the performance of Excel as it tries to connect to salesforce everytime you launch Excel.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using Data Loader in commandline mode (can be scripted meaning you could use Windows task scheduler on it too)? na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf‎

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Office Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) to write VBScript macros that connect to salesforce.

Comment: click into the nagivation that works. or try http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm